# Xcode Version 7.1 beta 3 Cannot attach to process when debugger is enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, logging

I can no longer install my app to my iPhone 6.
(With debugger enabled in the executable, when disabled it installs just fine)

I need to get some logging when from my device, but when I install it with debugging enable in the executable it can not attach the process, and the process does not stay alive. I need to restart the app, and when I try to attach the process after running it, it won't work. (error: failed to attach to process ID xxxx)

[image: Xcode error cannot attach]

When I look at my device, there are no logs at all.

[image]

Underneath the device debug log:

```
Oct  9 21:07:25 iPhone-Jurgend wifid[249] <Error>: WiFi:[466110445.299905]: Disable WoW requested by "IMDMessageServic"
Oct  9 21:07:25 iPhone-Jurgend IMDMessageServicesAgent[4483] <Warning>: WiFi is associated YES
Oct  9 21:07:25 iPhone-Jurgend IMDMessageServicesAgent[4483] <Warning>: WiFi is associated YES
Oct  9 21:07:27 iPhone-Jurgend searchd[4408] <Warning>: ====^^^^ DuetExpert missing data, count -> people:8 applicationDeepLinks:0 applications:8 requests:7 missingAllDataRequests:0
Oct  9 21:07:27 iPhone-Jurgend SpringBoard[4402] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Oct  9 21:07:28 iPhone-Jurgend securityd[1033] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Oct  9 21:07:28 iPhone-Jurgend securityd[1033] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Oct  9 21:07:28 iPhone-Jurgend amfid[4485] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[4484] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/72E27621-2237-4B8F-8B0F-E934ED0AC1CD (sandbox)
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend SpringBoard[4402] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend SpringBoard[4402] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend SpringBoard[4402] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend SpringBoard[4402] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend SpringBoard[4402] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend SpringBoard[4402] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend myDiveApp[4484] <Warning>:  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend myDiveApp[4484] <Warning>:    INFO: Localization changed from nl_BE to en_BE
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend myDiveApp[4484] <Warning>:  dbPathString: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/72E27621-2237-4B8F-8B0F-E934ED0AC1CD/Documents/myDb.db
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend myDiveApp[4484] <Warning>:    INFO: Localization changed from nl_BE to en_BE
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend myDiveApp[4484] <Warning>:    INFO: Localization changed from nl_BE to en_BE
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend myDiveApp[4484] <Warning>: localeIdentifier: en_BE
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend myDiveApp[4484] <Warning>: localeNameForKey: English (Belgium)
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend myDiveApp[4484] <Warning>:    INFO: Localization changed from nl_BE to en_BE
Oct  9 21:07:29 iPhone-Jurgend myDiveApp[4484] <Warning>:    INFO: Localization changed from nl_BE to en_BE
Oct  9 21:07:32 iPhone-Jurgend MobileSMS[4454] <Warning>: plugin com.swiftkey.SwiftKeyApp.Keyboard invalidated
Oct  9 21:07:33 iPhone-Jurgend myDiveApp[4484] <Warning>: Closed DB for applicationDidEnterBackground
Oct  9 21:07:33 iPhone-Jurgend SpringBoard[4402] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Oct  9 21:07:33 iPhone-Jurgend myDiveApp[4484] <Warning>: *** Error: 1000 Failed from sqlite3_exec('UPDATE SyncSettings SET lastExecCommand='2015-10-09 19:07:33 +0000' WHERE Id='7''). Error is: 'library routine called out of sequence'
Oct  9 21:07:34 iPhone-Jurgend syncdefaultsd[4486] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "enabled" on <APSConnection: 0x156d138e0>
Oct  9 21:07:36 iPhone-Jurgend MobileGestaltHelper[1036] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:276: server_access_check denied access to question UniqueDeviceID for pid 4486
Oct  9 21:07:36 iPhone-Jurgend syncdefaultsd[4486] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:151: pid 4486 (syncdefaultsd) does not have sandbox access for re6Zb+zwFKJNlkQTUeT+/w and IS NOT appropriately entitled
Oct  9 21:07:36 iPhone-Jurgend syncdefaultsd[4486] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:537: no access to UniqueDeviceID (see <rdar://problem/11744455>)
Oct  9 21:07:40 iPhone-Jurgend streaming_zip_conduit[4488] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder <LSApplicationProxy: 0x1276191e0> be.dictus.Test <(null) *Not found in database*>
Oct  9 21:07:40 iPhone-Jurgend streaming_zip_conduit[4488] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Not creating progress for <LSApplicationProxy: 0x1276191e0> be.dictus.Test <(null) *Not found in database*> since it is not a placeholder.
Oct  9 21:07:40 iPhone-Jurgend installd[4359] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/myDiveApp.app_sparse.ipa" type Developer (LSInstallType = (null)) requested by streaming_zip_conduit (pid 4488)
Oct  9 21:07:40 iPhone-Jurgend SpringBoard[4402] <Warning>: UNNotificationRegistrarConnectionListener connection invalidated
Oct  9 21:07:40 iPhone-Jurgend com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:be.dictus.Test[0x1fc4][4484]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
Oct  9 21:07:40 iPhone-Jurgend SpringBoard[4402] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:be.dictus.Test[0x1fc4]' exited abnormally via signal.
Oct  9 21:07:40 iPhone-Jurgend installd[4359] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundlePatch ID=be.dictus.Test; Version=20150929000023, ShortVersion=20150928000023>
Oct  9 21:07:40 iPhone-Jurgend installd[4359] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIInstallableBundlePatch applyPatchWithError:]: Attempting patch update of be.dictus.Test from 20150929000023 (20150928000023) to 20150929000023 (20150928000023)
Oct  9 21:07:40 iPhone-Jurgend misagent[4269] <Notice>: attempt to install invalid profile: 0xe8008012
Oct  9 21:07:40 iPhone-Jurgend installd[4359] <Error>: 0x16e087000 -[MIInstallableBundle _installEmbeddedProfileInBundle:]: Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008012 (This provisioning profile cannot be installed on this device.)
Oct  9 21:07:41 iPhone-Jurgend securityd[1033] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Oct  9 21:07:41 iPhone-Jurgend securityd[1033] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Oct  9 21:07:41 iPhone-Jurgend installd[4359] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Oct  9 21:07:41 iPhone-Jurgend installd[4359] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for be.dictus.Test is now at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/85FF8F2F-DD5D-4178-8772-E3ADF98FDD5C
Oct  9 21:07:41 iPhone-Jurgend installd[4359] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for be.dictus.Test at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/10108176-D834-4322-840A-EA0C18CFA353
Oct  9 21:07:41 iPhone-Jurgend installd[4359] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 0.00s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.35s, Verifying: 0.20s; Overall: 1.20s
Oct  9 21:07:41 iPhone-Jurgend pkd[4264] <Warning>: releasing plug-in hold 3FA1E042-EFE9-4C78-8A2D-DC96149714E2 at client's request
```

Seems to have some wrong with the install procedure:
LaunchServices: Not creating progress for <LSApplicationProxy: 0x1276191e0> be.dictus.Test <(null) *Not found in database*> since it is not a placeholder.

Comment: Instead of clicking "View Device Logs", expand the text area at the bottom of the devices window to see the device console messages.  Is there anything in there related to the installation or launch of your app?

Comment: Xcode got a PID, so the app must have launched.  But looking in the Device Logs still might help.  Search for logs from "debugserver" - that's the debugger agent that runs on the device, and you might see some system messages about why the attempt to get the task port was denied.  Those should give some more hints.

Comment: Also, make sure you are building the Debug and not the Release configuration of your app.  Apps need a specific entitlement before the system will allow the debugger to attach to them, and Xcode adds that entitlement to the Debug configuration automatically, but not to the Release configuration.

Comment: The scheme is the debug scheme, ( I double checked )
No there are no device logs there

@Phillip: what text area do you mean, al is white and empty in my device screen

Comment: There's a small control at the bottom-left corner of the white area.

Comment: @Philiip: I found what you meant :D much thanks, I guess this debug logging will eventually tell me what my App is doing wrong when debug is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by cleaning up my info.plist.

- removed -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 in C compiler settings
- set Implicit Bool Conversions to 'YES'
- set Generate Profiling code to 'NO'

Answer (score 1):

Two things to try:

1. Reboot your device
2. Restart Xcode

Always worth trying in situations like this :)  If really desperate, reboot your Mac, too!

Comment: Tried both a couple of times with no success